# How to fill iframe element which already has html in it with new html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I have an Iframe in which I hawe opened a html document with header and body. I have html string that I wish to use to replace original Iframes html body. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that something to this affect will do the trick if the iframe is being served from the same domain as the page itself*.

```
var html_string = "<p>hello world</p>";
$('#iFrame').contents().find('#id_to_replace').html(html_string);
```

*If it's not, then you are hosed as the browser will prevent access to an iframe of a different domain for security reasons.  Though you could also consider piping the content you need in the iframe through your own server and displaying it that way, which would then allow your javascript access to the iframe content, although it's certainly not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the JavaScript is in the document that contains the iFrame, something along these lines may work:

```
getElementById(yourIFrameId).document.body.innerHTML = "Your HTML String";
```